# Deparse and (un)escape quotes

Tags: r

I have the following list:

```
lst <- list(a = "", b = 2)
```

and want to deparse it to text:

```
> deparse(lst, width.cutoff = 100)
[1] "structure(list(a = \"\", b = \"\"), .Names = c(\"a\", \"b\"))"
```

and then i want to run the text as code (in the console):

```
> structure(list(a = \"\", b = \"\"), .Names = c(\"a\", \"b\"))
Error: unexpected input in "structure(list(a = \"
```

I know it Fails, because of the backslashes: (without them it works obviously).

```
structure(list(a = "", b = ""), .Names = c("a", "b"))
```

**Question:**

How can i avoid creating the backslashes?

**What i tried:**

I went through the given Parameter. Backtick seemed like a candidate, but didnt work. Using gsub to replace them is a candidate, but way to dirty i guess,..

**Tools:**

R 3.4.3
Rstudio 1.1.447

Update: Upgrade to 3.6 - similar issue.

```
> lst <- list(a = "", b = 2)
> deparse(lst, width.cutoff = 100)
[1] "list(a = \"\", b = 2)"
> list(a = \"\", b = 2)
Error: unexpected input in "list(a = \"
```

Comment: Your output is not reproducible  in `R 3.6`   `deparse(lst, width.cutoff = 100)#
[1] "list(a = \"\", b = 2)"`

Comment: I think in the recent versions, there are some changes in the structure.  Please update your R and try

Comment: interesting as well. I made an edit for the versions i use. I am using R 3.4.3 currently. But i guess you also get an error, pasting your result `list(a = \"\", b = 2)` to the console?

Comment: I am not sure about the intention of this exercise.  I get `eval(parse(text = deparse(lst)))#$a
[1] ""

$b
[1] 2`. Also, as we have different R versions, it will not be a fair comparison of output

Comment: eval(parse(text=…))) will work i am aware. I am asking using the string as described in the question. Intention might look strange i know., its About creating Code files programmatically,..

Comment: Yes, but if my R version is not giving the error as you have, it is not reproducible.  For me `dput(lst)#
list(a = "", b = 2)`. There is no `structure` or `.Names`

Comment: If the. output is `out`, then `out1 <- gsub('"', "'", out)` and then copy/paste the output on the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of ways to modify the behavior.  One way is to print with `cat` on the console, copy and paste that (used `R 3.6.0`)

```
out <- deparse(lst, width.cutoff = 100)
cat(out, sep="\n")
#list(a = "", b = 2)
list(a = "", b = 2)
#$a
#[1] ""

#$b
#[1] 2
```

Note that `cat` also have a `file` argument if the output needs to be written to some file and used it later

---

Or use `gsub` to remove the `"` and replace with single quotes (`'`)

```
out1 <- gsub('"', "'", out)
out1
#[1] "list(a = '', b = 2)"
```